# My button is executing two or more times

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone

I'm trying to avoid doing async task two or more times when someone double clicks a button.

When my app has a delay my await _navigation.ShowMyButton(); will go two or more times.

```
    private readonly ICommand MyButton;
    private bool? canExecuteMyButton { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.MyButton = new Command((nothing) =>
            {
                GoToMyButton();
            }, this.CanExecuteMyButton);
    }

    private async void GoToMyButton()
    {
        canExecuteMyButton = false;
        await _navigation.ShowMyButton();
        canExecuteMyButton = true;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteMyButton(object state)
    {
        if (canExecuteMyButton == null)
            return true;

        return (bool)canExecuteMyButton;
    }
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: How about just checking if `canExecuteMyButton`  is true, before calling `_navigation.ShowMyButton()`?

Comment: The problem is that it's always executing.

Comment: Try raising `CanExecuteChanged` of command in canExecuteMyButton `set{_canExecuteMyButton = value;MyButton.CanExecuteChanged();}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work better:

```
private async void GoToMyButton()
{
    if (canExecuteMyButton)
    {
        canExecuteMyButton = false;
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        await _navigation.ShowMyButton();
        canExecuteMyButton = true;
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```